# How to get Stanford CoreNLP to use a training model you created?

Tags: java, model, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I just created a training model for stanfordCoreNLP, so I have a bunch of files that look like this:

[image]

Now, how do I tell CoreNLP to use the model I created and not the models that come with coreNLP? Is it something I pass in the command line or something in my java code like:

```
props.put("sentiment.model");
```

I noticed there's a jar file in my coreNLP library called stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models.jar. Does this jar file have anything to do with what I want to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in Java:

```
props.put("sentiment.model", "path/to/model");
```

on command line:

```
-sentiment.model path/to/model
```

Comment: If I were to just do it through the java code, does the application get "trained" with this model every time I run it? I guess what I'm trying to say is do I have to keep this line of code every time I run the application or do I just do it once and then comment it out since coreNLP has already seen the model  and is therefore "trained". I hope that made sense.

Comment: To be clear, this process involves two main steps 1. training a model 2. making predictions on unseen text with your new model.  Once you train the model the model is saved in a file like model-0014-93.73.ser.gz.  Your application which is predicting sentiments for new unseen tweets will load that file and make predictions based on that model.  So props.put("sentiment.model", "path/to/model") is an instruction to use that model, it has nothing to do with the training phase.  This is assuming you are building a StanfordCoreNLP pipeline object in your Java code with the "sentiment" annotator.

Comment: This page has a lot of information about annotating documents with Stanford CoreNLP: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Comment: The part where it has "sentiment.model", is that arbitrary or is it the name of my model? Because I have plenty of model files, as you can see in the picture, so I don't know what to put in that part. @StanfordNLPHelp

Comment: You should put model-0014-93.73.ser.gz , which is your highest scoring model.  The "93.73" is the model's F1 score.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that was the F1 score. Thanks for clearing that up!