# Multiple Stanford CoreNLP model files made, which one is the correct one to use?

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I made a sentiment analysis model using Standford CoreNLP's library. So I have a bunch of ser.gz files that look like the following: 
[image]

I was wondering what model to use in my java code, but based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725007/how-to-get-stanford-corenlp-to-use-a-training-model-you-created),

I just used the model with the highest F1 score, which in this case is model-0014-93.73.ser.gz. And in my java code, I pointed to the model I want to use by using the following line:

```
    props.put("sentiment.model", "/path/to/model-0014-93.73.ser.gz.");
```

However, by referring to just that model, am I excluding the sentiment analysis from the other models that were made? Should I be referring to all the model files to make sure I "covered" all the bases or does the highest scoring model trump everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should point to only the single highest scoring model. The code has no way to make use of multiple models at the same time.